# Save data between multiple activities

Tags: android

First of all, sorry for newbie questions..

In my app I have two activities.

**Activity A** is in general a registration form with edittexts, autocompletetextviews, spinners and two buttons X and Y which leads to Activity B , practically a map activity. Applying startActivityForResult for button X I go to Activity B taking some data, then back to A ( onActivityResult ) then button Y leads with same procedure to Activity B and finally back to A.

The problems is that Activity A doesn't remember results from button X procedure when button Y ends its own.

**Question1**.  Filling edittexts in activity A, going to activity B and back to A doesn't prevent activity A to hold this kind of data contrary to startActivityForResult and onActivityResult . Why is that;

**Question 2:** What is the proper way to save data from button X in activity A so that activity holds results both from the two button procedure when button Y finishes its own;

Thanks in advance..

Comment: any code that u would have tried ? plz post here? if not hv u tried shared pref?

Comment: You can go for the `ApplicationContext` to save data that can be used by multiple activities.. Also you can use any singleton pattern..

Comment: how do you store data from button A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@FKSI is correct that the proper way to do this is using Intents Extras. However, I use Several Fragments inside each activity and when I have a mix of many activities and fragments all playing together AND if the data is not a lot, I find it very easy to use a [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). Using [getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()) as the Context, saving any SharedPreferences is accessible from anywhere in the package of the app.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to send simple data between activies is using extras. Have a look at [Android official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Answer (score -1):

If I dont misunderstand, you just want to save temp data. I recommend you to use [Application class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html). An example can be found here: [Example](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/5/24/how-to-use-application-object-of-android). Hope it helps.

Comment: As the link may get broken in future, you should include an example in your answer. Also, your answer suggests a bad practice, as counter-argued [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/python-why-are-global-variables-evil)

Comment: @Marius: this is subject to discussion. so just claiming that global variables are bad practice it is not enough. there are arguments for it and against it, practically as anything else. i personally find them useful in certain cases specifically from performance perspective. however, i agree that for this particular case not useful

Comment: You answer a question and disagree with your own answer.

Comment: i did not answer any question.

Comment: @Marius: 1st: Link is not broken yet, I checked it (It's just discussion, why need code?). 2nd: I dont think save everything to db is better idea. with some small things, it's not neccessary, that's why Application class exists.

Comment: Can anyone answer to question 1; I want to understand the logic behind that